# How do I connect Microsoft 365 Copilot to a data source?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I've read (and watched) in several places that Microsoft 365 Copilot should be able to integrate with external data sources using graph connectors.  However, I've been unable to find how to do this.

**Steps so far**

1. Started a free trial for ServiceNow
2. Navigated to Microsoft 365 admin center -> Search & Intelligence
3. Added a [ServiceNow data source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftsearch/servicenow-catalog-connector)
4. Created a Result Type for the data source
5. Created a Vertical for the data source
6. Performed a full-crawl (source now shows as "Ready" with 144 items indexed)
7. Started a free trial for [Copilot Studio](https://copilotstudio.microsoft.com/)
8. Created a new Copilot instance

Assuming what I've done so far is correct, what's next?  How do integrate my 365 Copliot with the data source I've just mapped?

Answer (score 0):

I got to the bottom of it (thanks to [this answer](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/copilot-formerly-bing-chat/copilot-i-ve-mapped-a-365-data-source-now-what/m-p/3998244/highlight/true#M124) on a Microsoft forum).

It turns out that Microsoft 365 Copilot and Copilot (formerly Bing Chat Enterprise) are two different services.

Ironically the forum on which I found this answer was:
Home > Microsoft 365 > Copilot (formerly Bing Chat Enterprise)